# Why does HandlerThread require a name?

Tags: android

Why does the android [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) require a name for the Constructor?

> **Public constructors**
>
> ---
>
> `HandlerThread(String name)`
>
> `HandlerThread(String name, int priority)`
>
> Constructs a HandlerThread.

I.e. why is there no constructor `new HandlerThread()` without arguments? For what is the name used internally, and what can I use it for?

Searching for 'name' in the docs only gives these constructors as result.

Comment: It's for debugging purposes, so you can distinguish thread activity in your logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've looked up the source code.

HandlerThread uses the name just to call the `java.lang.Thread(String name)` constructor.

The doc of java.lang.Thread says:

> Every thread has a name for identification purposes. More than one
>   thread may have the same name. If a name is not specified when a
>   thread is created, a new name is generated for it.

Comment: Thanks! So I can pass any string value that I want, if I understood correctly. Just out of curiosity, does that include `null`?

Comment: Unfortunately not... Thread checks if `name` is null and if so throws a `NullPointerException`

Comment: "Every thread has a name for identification purposes. More than one thread may have the same name." I lol'd so hard